# One word to say make something lose its function

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I am searching for a verb to express:

- make something lose its function or make something inefficient.

for instance:

> the symbol loses its special meaning in that context.

I wanna say:

> the symbol is 'verb'ed.

Comment: **incapacitate, disable, cripple, disenable, put sth out of action, immobilize, weaken, enfeeble, exhaust**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it is specific to biology, but "denatured" would be perfect here.